# Create strongly-typed view from viewModel without render the ViewModel to the DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I know this question has already been asked repeatedly, but I can't seem to find an answer that will fit my needs:
I have this model:

```
[Table("AppUser", Schema = "AppUsers")]
public class AppUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AppUserID { get; set; }  //Primary key
    [Required]
    public string UserIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int StreetNo { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string AboutMeDescription { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? VolunteeringRadius { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public float? RankAvg { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool? IsEmailApproved { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool? IsSMSApproved { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? PrefferedContactMethodID { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? RegisterationStatusID { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool? IsFirstLogin { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool? IsWebRegister { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? LanguageID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AppUserTypeID { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CityId { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? OrganizationID { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [ForeignKey("AppUserTypeID")]
    public virtual AppUserType AppUserType { get; set; } //Navigation property
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; } //Navigation property
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationID")]
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

which, using entity framework code first approach, renders as a new table in my DbContext and in turn in my SQL Database.

I also have this ViewModel

```
public class AppUserCreateViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int AppUserID { get; set; }  //Primary key
    public string UserIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int StreetNo { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AppUserTypeID { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CityId { get; set; } //Foreign key
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? OrganizationID { get; set; } //Foreign key
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AppUserTypes { get; set; } //Navigation property
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; } //Navigation property
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

I probably am doing something wrong here, since I want to create a "Create" view from this ViewModel, but to my understanding, I cannot scaffold it, since it will than create an Empty table in the Database (named "AppUserCreateViewModel"). I really have no need in that table (the table I wish to use is "AppUser".

So my questions are:

1. What should I do if I wish to create a strongly-typed view, by using my viewModel, but without creating a corresponding table in my DB, and to bind this view to my AppUser table?
2. Should I be using the Repository pattern? Or is it an overkill?
3. I want the CreateViewModel will render 3 DropDownLists (AppUserTypes, Cities and Organizations) - What's the best way to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your 'view model' needs to be in a separate folder (say) `/ViewModels`. It should not have `[Key]` or `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` attributes which are not applicable to view models

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is in a ViewModels folder. But I must have key, otherwise I cannot scaffold.